# How to work with postman api collection data

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner

I'm very new to Postman Api testing environment, here i got to use this one https://www.getpostman.com/collections/a0afd85b4642ab7251ba

Please how do i get to extract the collection and test it as REST API

I have tried extracted these data

```
"item": [
    {
      "name": "GetCustomerSalary_BVN",
      "event": [
        {
          "listen": "test",
          "script": {
            "type": "text/javascript",
            "exec": [
              "https://login.remita.net/remita/exapp/api/v1/send/api/loansvc/data/api/v2/payday/salary/history/ph"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "listen": "prerequest",
          "script": {
            "type": "text/javascript",
            "exec": [
              "var merchantId = \"27768931\";",
              "var apiKey = \"Q1dHREVNTzEyMzR8Q1dHREVNTw==\";",
              "var apiToken = \"SGlQekNzMEdMbjhlRUZsUzJCWk5saDB6SU14Zk15djR4WmkxaUpDTll6bGIxRCs4UkVvaGhnPT0=\";",
              "var d = new Date();",
              "var requestId = d.getTime();",
              "var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1101233);",
              "var authorisationCode = randomnumber;",
              "var apiHash = CryptoJS.SHA512(apiKey + requestId + apiToken);",
              "var authorization = \"remitaConsumerKey=\" + apiKey + \", remitaConsumerToken=\" + apiHash;",
              "postman.setGlobalVariable('merchantId', merchantId);",
              "postman.setGlobalVariable('apiKey', apiKey);",
              "postman.setGlobalVariable('requestId', requestId);",
              "postman.setGlobalVariable('authorisationCode', authorisationCode);",
              "postman.setGlobalVariable('authorization', authorization);",
              "",
              "console.log(authorization)"
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
```

but not sure of what to do next

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run this collection then you can simply import it in your postman and run all APIs at once by 'Run collection'. With this, you can the see response of all APIs (in your case 6 APIs).
If you want to execute all APIs individually and manually then select each API after importing the collection and run them to see the response.

Comment: Thanks, but I am not too familiar with the process of importing and running the API, please guide me on how I go about it. Thanks

Comment: Open postman -> go to 'My workspace' -> click 'Import' -> Select 'Link' in Import dialog box -> Enter URL of postman collection and click 'Continue'